# Issue with saving RDD as a JSON file, considering that size of each RDD never exceeds 10 Mb

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I am reading DStream of JSON strings from Kafka using Spark Streaming. I need to save the input data on S3 in JSON format. This is the way I do it, however when the amount of data in batch is around 5Mb, it takes very long time to execute this code. Can it be optimized?
I need to save data in JSON files (`*.json`), because there is another program that uses these files and reads them as follows:

`var df = sqlContext.read.json("s3n://" + bucketNameData + "/" + directoryS3 + "/*.json")`

So, in order to save RDD as a sinlge JSON file, I tried `rdd.map(lambda x :json.loads(x))
.coalesce(1, shuffle=True).saveAsTextFile('examples/src/main/resources/demo.json')`, but it saves the data in a hadoopish way, and as far as I understand, I want be able to later read them as I shown above (to get `df` from json files). Therefore I switched to `amazonS3Client`, however I feel like it might be optimized. Maybe I should convert `rdd` to DataFrame or so, and then save it in some way as JSON?

```
val mySet = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(Map("metadataBrokerList"->metadataBrokerList,
                                           "bucketNameData"->bucketNameData,
                                           "bucketNameCode"->bucketNameCode))

dstreamdata.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
      rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
        val producer = UtilsTest.createProducer(mySet.value("metadataBrokerList"))
        val amazonS3Client = UtilsTest.createS3()
        iter.foreach { msg =>
          if (msg.nonEmpty) {
            // Save messages to S3
            val CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json"
            val fileContentBytes = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContentBytes)
            val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
            metadata.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE)
            metadata.setContentLength(fileContentBytes.length)
            val datetime = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
            val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd-HH-mm-ss")
            val setID = formatter.format(datetime)
            val filePath = mySet.value("bucketNameData") + "/file_" + setID + ".json"
            val putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(mySet.value("bucketNameData"), filePath, fileInputStream, metadata)
            amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest)

//---
```

Answer (score 0):

your direct putObject() will be more efficient as there's no copy in the rename() normally used to commit work. You may have problems when dealing with failure and replay of work though.

If you do use newHadooopRDD, you can significantly reduce the overhead with commit algorithm 2:

`spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by `If you do use newHadooopRDD`? Is it some library that I can integrate in my `pom.xml`?

Comment: no, it means you create the RDD with `SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD()`